# Records inserted in REDIS are not saved

Tags: redis

When we add any records(in the form of hashes or sets), do we need to COMMIT in order to save them.
Is there a similar provision in REDIS?
I have created a virtual machine and I added records in form of hashes to my REDIS Cache on my m/c.

However,when I restart my Redis client and query for my records,they do not exist!
Sincerely appreciate anyone's reply on an urgent basis.
Thanks!

Comment: sry guys,apparently i didnt SAVE the added records using the appropraite command...

Answer (score 1):

You can use `SAVE` as you apparently already discovered or you can use `BGSAVE` to run the saving task in the background and continue operating.

Comment: Indeed, my brain really wants the command to be `DBSAVE` and I always type that even in the command prompt.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **AOF** feature for better results

Answer (score 0):

To see what happens "online" with your storage you can use "monitor" command. Just type it to console after redis-cli entering:

The sample:

```
user@user:~/Projects$ redis-cli
redis 127.0.0.1:6379> monitor
OK
1361101579.987123 "monitor"
1361102054.206754 "set" "keySample" "valSample" // in another console window I run "set keySample valSample"
```